# Send-MailMessage blocked in background if supplied with credential argument

Tags: powershell, email

I'm trying to run `Send-MailMessage` in background using credentials I have retrieved before via `Get-Credential` and stored in the `$creds` variable.

The following command will almost immediately be blocked in background:

`Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Send-MailMessage -to "test@test.com" -from "test@test.com" -Subject "2342332" -Credential $creds }`

Running `Get-Job` or assigning the previous command to a variable and displaying it will give me this status:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
25     Job25           BackgroundJob   Blocked       True            localhost             Send-MailMessage -to ...
```

Running the exact same command directly (without `Start-Job`) will complete immediately (in this case it will fail as I haven't provided an smtp server). Also, running the exact same command without the `-Credential` argument will complete the job directly, as well as running in the background (it will fail for the same missing smtp server reason, but that's not important).

Is there a way to supply credentials to this command, preferably with `Get-Credential` and be able to run it with `Start-Job`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background jobs are run in a separate child process, and `$creds` does not exist in said separate process. `Send-MailMessage` doesn't accept `$null`-values as arguments to `-Credential`, and therefore prompts the caller for a valid non-null argument.

You can reproduce this blocking behavior in an interactive shell:

```
PS ~> Send-MailMessage -Credential:$null

PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
User:
```

Since the job is running in a runspace with no interactive capabilities, nothing can be done to satisfy the request and the job state is blocked.

Change `-Credential $creds` to `-Credential $using:creds` to force powershell to copy the `$creds` variable to the job's runspace:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Send-MailMessage -to "test@test.com" -from "test@test.com" -Subject "2342332" -Credential $using:creds }
```

Or pass it as an explicit argument when calling `Start-Job`:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Send-MailMessage -to "test@test.com" -from "test@test.com" -Subject "2342332" -Credential $args[0] } -ArgumentList $creds
```

Comment: I'm surprised that I couldn't find more information about this. I thought this would be a more popular issue. Thanks a bunch.